# Projects NEW,7+days,14+days Select row count by Age/Date query

Tags: mysql, select

I am racking my brain as to how this might work. I have tried a number of variations and can not seem to get accurate results.

I need to check my cdate field which holds the the date and time stamp. Then i need to check for new projects less than 7days and display the row count, then for projects between 7 and 14days and display the row count and finally for projects over 14days old and display the row count.

What i have is a dashboard that shows a number count for those ( NEW / 7+ days / 14+ days )

This is my table field:

```
cdate
2011-07-29 19:21:29
2011-08-05 19:25:14
2011-08-05 19:25:23
2011-03-29 19:21:29
2011-08-05 19:25:23
2011-08-05 19:25:23
```

And this is my current queries:

```
$quotesNEW_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM projects WHERE status=0 AND cdate >= NOW() AND cdate <= NOW() + INTERVAL 6 DAY") or die(mysql_error());  
$quotes_result_new = mysql_num_rows($quotesNEW_sql); 

$quotesSEVEN_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM projects WHERE status=0 AND cdate >= NOW() AND cdate <= NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY") or die(mysql_error());  
$quotes_result_seven = mysql_num_rows($quotesSEVEN_sql); 

$quotesFOURTEEN_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM projects WHERE status=0 AND cdate >= NOW() AND cdate <= NOW() + INTERVAL 15 DAY") or die(mysql_error());  
$quotes_result_fourteen = mysql_num_rows($quotesFOURTEEN_sql);
```

Thanks in advance :)
John

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the count, you could use `GROUP BY` to do it with a single query.

```
SELECT COUNT(crate), FLOOR(ABS(DATEDIFF(cdate, NOW()) / 7)) AS day_interval
FROM projects
WHERE status = 0
GROUP BY day_interval;
```

`day_interval` is broken down as follows:

- 0 = New
- 1 = 7-13 days
- 2 = 14+ days

Comment: How do i write the day_interval part? 0=new 1=7-13 2=14+

Comment: Hi Jason, im still not understanding it. I have three divs and in each one i echo the result count. I cant seem to get it to work

Comment: You'll be interested in the `COUNT(create)` part. Run the query using `mysql_query();` and then loop over the results. I'd recommend testing the query (e.g. with phpMyAdmin) to ensure it does what you want.